# Changing $dx$ to $\operatorname d\!x$

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editing, specific-user

Seems like [someone](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3936/arjang?tab=activity&sort=revisions) has gone on a bizarre edit spree, deciding to randomly change $dx$ to $\operatorname d\!x$ (with no other edits). This is purely a matter of stylistic choice, and I find it really annoying to have ancient questions bumped for just this. Some of the edited posts are more than a year old.

Should such edits be discouraged? (I think so.)

Comment: I have [pinged](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191736/help-with-integrating-displaystyle-int-0-infty-dfrac-log-x2x2-1#comment2021157_191736) the user you mention. (I think it is good to let them know about the thread on meta.)

Comment: Some related posts on TeX.SE: [What's the proper way to typeset a differential operator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator)
and other posts shown there among linked questions. Maybe also [Is there a preference of when to use \text and \mathrm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/is-there-a-preference-of-when-to-use-text-and-mathrm).

Comment: Changing was not random, the \operatorname seemed more appropriate, how ever I want to hear what council of elders has to say on styling of differential operator.

Comment: @Arjang: Do you think we should edit $\bf R$ to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Arjang Surely it was random. The same questions you edited had several answers with italic $d$:s which you left unchanged.

Comment: I'm sure we've had discussions of innessential edits before. This certainly qualifies. Don't do it. Please.

Comment: @mrf : I couldn't adjust every occurrence :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson : inessential or better styled? In either case I'll take it easy on manual  editing, the problem I was testing has alternative solution and manual editing is not the answer to have uniformity and following proper style.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Depending on the context. The changes were in line with proper use of \operatorname

Comment: @Arjang While I personally prefer the roman $\mathrm{d}$, not everybody does - but the more important thing is that even if $dx$ was categorically wrong (which it isn't), changing it bumps lots of old questions to the front page, hiding new questions, and it's not worth doing this for such a minor change.

Comment: @Arjang: Uniform and proper style? According to whom? I don't think there is such a thing as universally accepted style in math.

Comment: I dislike the Roman *d* and much prefer $dx$. I don't change other people's $\mathrm{d}x$, and I expect them not to muck about with my $dx$.

Comment: I wonder what would the reception would have been if this had been about $sin$ vs $\sin$, or $Aut$ vs $\operatorname{Aut}$. Specifically, I wonder if @Jyrki would have said the same thing?

Comment: @user1729 However, there are things that are not uniform. And anyways we all know the rules for minor edits. If someone edited an old post only to change `$y=sin x$` to `$y=\sin x$`, I would certainly reject it. No matter I am a professional math typographer.

Comment: @tohecz I disagree with your two points. Firstly, there are no "rules" for "minor edits" - the [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) gives a possible reason for an edit as "to correct minor mistakes", while it says that "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged", not banned. "Rules" come from user consensus, which is what we are here to discuss.

Comment: Secondly, I do not think blanket rejection is realistic: rejection should always depend on context. For example, I would reject a `sin x` to `\sin x` in an old post with few views and a negative score, but not in an old post with a high score and lots of views. So any "rules" we have should, in my opinion, be fuzzy and not concrete.

Comment: A good question, @user1729. My honest answer is that I'm not sure how I would have reacted. The analogue is not perfect, because all the TeX-books explain why `\sin x` is better. In the present case it's IMHO more like the battle between $\mathbf{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}$. I used to fight tooth and nail in favor of $\mathbf{R}$ (which may be why you asked me specifically :-). I have given up that struggle since, and have adopted a chameleon's policy of using whichever the OP did. BTW I like your suggestion of having a fuzzy rule. The frequency of edits is also a factor.

Comment: (cont'd) So it behooves me to do my `Lindelof -> Lindelöf` edits in bursts of 2-3 at max.

Comment: @Jyrki: I wince, but I generally just don’t bother with that one (and `Erdos` or `Erdös` to `Erdős`, and `Sierpinski` to `Sierpiński`, and ...) unless either I’m fixing something more important, or the question or answer is pretty new.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11869/23353

Comment: Could we just use $\int f(x) m(dx)$ instead?

Comment: @Jyrki You attribute to much knowledge on my part. I do actually remember someone preferring $\mathbf{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, but I had no idea who it might have been! I specifically asked you because of your sentence "I don't think there is such a thing as universally accepted style in math", but as I re-read this now I wonder if you were talking about "style of 'd'", not "style of anything". Also, I agree that frequency of edits is also a factor, but this is often hard to spot (which can be frustrating!).

Comment: (Incidentally, @Jyrki, I also think that $\mathbb{R}$ vs $\mathbf{R}$ depends on context, and so should also be a fuzzy rule. All rules should be fuzzy! For example, I feel that when introducing the reals (in typewritten notes) $\mathbb{R}$ is better because it is more prevalent in the literature. On the other hand, there is no such thing as an [$\mathbb{R}$-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tree)!)

Comment: IMO, questions being "bumped" even by minor edits is a technology problem in StackExchange that should be addressed there (e.g. through a "this is a minor edit" checkbox like Wikipedia has had for years). That tiny improvements in style or typography are being officially discouraged because the software is too dumb to know when to bump and when to leave is surely not ideal.

Comment: @user1729 "There is no such thing as an $\mathbb{R}$-tree"? I have seen them typeset like this (and not just in papers I've written).

Comment: ^^ seconding Shane O Rourke's comment; even on that same Wikipedia page, Bestvina's notes in the references have $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Shane Pity, I thought it was a good example! Maybe I accidentally exaggerate, or maybe I am just misled because $\mathbf{R}$ occurs relatively frequently, which is something I had never seen before back when I was reading about them!

Comment: @pew But if the edit is not an improvement in typography, rather the opposite, like here?

Comment: Don't edits have to be approved by someone? If so, can't there be both “accept and bump“ and “accept and leave in place” options, so that posts with _significant_ edits refresh in the general feed, but those with _insignificant_ (but helpful) edits like formatting don't refresh?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From typographical point of view, the question whether `d` in `dx` is upright or italic is not clear at all, it varies from author to author, from sub-field to sub-field and from journal to journal. Therefore I think that **we should not unify the style across the site** and **rather leave it to the authors**.

What is not questionable, though, is that `dx` has to be separated from the preceding contents by a thin space (`\,` in LaTeX/MathJaX), unless there already is a visual separation (which is the case more-or-less only when the integrand is a large parenthesis).

And no matter what, editing `dx` into `\mathrm{d}x` or `\operatorname{d}x`, as well as adding the thin space, it all certainly qualifies as a minor edit.

Comment: Minor point: there is a difference between *minor* and *too minor*. For example, $x\mapsto -x$... is minor, but not necessarily *too* minor...

Comment: @user1729 No, I believe that the one you show is _small_ (in length), but not _minor_ (in importance) ;)

Comment: Touché...minor is an adjective, so really we each should have followed it by a noun. You meant "minor in importance" while I meant "minor in size". I doubt SE will change the close reason "too minor" based on this imprecision though...

Comment: @user1729  "too minor" rejection reason for edits does not exist any more.

Comment: Well, [this tex.SE answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14822/430) states ISO 31/XI suggests the upright version, which might be considered a standard. However I agree it's too minor to justify an edit - though providing a global `\d` or similar might improve the readability of the "correct" typesetting.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I suggest leaving ISO for the engineers and staying with typography traditions in maths: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator/14822#comment27485_14838

Comment: True dat... Personally I'd prefer spending less time with norms (_or_ typography) and more time with contents, but somehow my job's currently quite the opposite :/

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `\ ` that should always precede a $dx$ in an integral.

Comment: @Arkamis It's not interword space ```\ ``` ! It's the thin space ```\,``` !!!

Comment: Either space will do -- as long as there is a space.

Comment: I just think we need some space. Maybe take a little break, meet up at the next partition.

Comment: It doesnt cares absolutely nothing, being "official" or not it really doesnt care at all. It meaning is obvious, it doesnt lead to confusion.

Comment: @tohecz I prefer not to typeset a space every time (mainly due to my laziness), since `\mathrm dx` creates a visual separation by change of font already. I have even included a `\dd` command in my own utility package just to abbreviate the `\mathrm d`, but I wouldn't worry about spacing **if** there is some other visual separation. $\int xdx$ is barely readable, but to me $\int x\mathrm dx$ is good enough.

Comment: @AlexR There are zillions of ways how to do it in LaTeX, and zillions of people who like one and hate another one and ...

Comment: @AlexR: Whereas for me $\int x\mathrm dx$ requires significantly more effort to parse visually than $\int xdx$, though both are vastly inferior to $\int x\,dx$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Took me some time to see the difference between the 2nd and 3rd example